# Insert Data on Google Sheets specifically

Tags: google-sheets, ios7

I have this code that can insert a Data in Google Sheets but only on a STRAIGHT row:

```
NSArray *Worksheets = [mWorksheetFeed entries];

if ( [Worksheets count] > 0)
    [self fetchSelectedWorksheet];



NSArray *entries = [mEntryFeed entries];

for (int l=0; l < [entries count]; l++)
{
    GDataFeedBase *entry = [entries objectAtIndex:l];
    GDataSpreadsheetCell *cell = [(GDataEntrySpreadsheetCell *)entry cell];

    NSLog(@"%@-%@-%@",[cell resultString], [cell inputString], [[entry title] stringValue]);

}
if ([entries count]>0)
{
    GDataEntrySpreadsheetCell * lastCell = [entries lastObject];
    NSString * title = [[lastCell title] stringValue];
    NSString * lastRow = [[title componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:
                           [[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] invertedSet]]
                          componentsJoinedByString:@""];

    for (int l = 0; l < resultRow.count; l++ )
    {
        GDataSpreadsheetCell * cell = [GDataSpreadsheetCell cellWithRow:[lastRow intValue] + 1 column:l+1 inputString:[resultRow objectAtIndex:l] numericValue:nil resultString:nil];

        // create a cellEntry object that will contain the cell
        GDataEntrySpreadsheetCell * cellEntry = [GDataEntrySpreadsheetCell spreadsheetCellEntryWithCell:cell];

        // upload the cellEntry to your spreadsheet
        GDataServiceGoogleSpreadsheet *service = [self spreadsheetService];
        GDataEntryWorksheet *worksheet = [self selectedWorksheet];
        [service fetchEntryByInsertingEntry:cellEntry
                                 forFeedURL: [[worksheet cellsLink] URL]
                                   delegate:self
                          didFinishSelector:nil];
    }
}
```

Now what I want to do is, instead of a straight row, to insert a data from UITextField to any specific cell, e.g for the first text field I want that to be C5 and the second textfield to be inserted into G11.

Comment: is this is a iOS 7 specific question?